# React, GraphQL, Apollo add data to the database via form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I have setup basic the GraphQL Playground and am able to query or add objects which in my case are cars. I am even able to query cars and display them on front end but I am having issues in terms of adding or updating the database via GraphQL by entering data in to a form. I am using the use state hook and as soon as I add a use state hook the page stops loading and I come up with a blank page as in it stops loading:

The code is below:

````
export default function CarForm() {
    const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
        name: '',
        mileage: '',
        dailyPrice: '',
        monthlyPrice: '',
        gas: '',
        gearType: '',
        thumbnailUrl: ''
    })

    const [carForm] = useMutation(ADD_NEW_CAR, {
        variables: {
            name: formState.name,
            mileage: formState.mileage,
            dailyPrice: formState.dailyPrice,
            monthlyPrice: formState.monthlyPrice,
            gas: formState.gas,
            gearType: formState.gearType

        }
    });

    return (

        <div>

            <h1>
                Submit your car
            </h1>
            <Form>
                <h5 >make and model of car :
                    <input className="field" type="text" value={formState.name}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                            setFormState({
                                ...formState,
                                name: e.target.value
                            })
                        } />
                </h5>

                <h5>
                    Mileage
                    <input className="field" type="text" value={formState.mileage}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                            setFormState({
                                ...formState,
                                mileage: e.target.value
                            })
                        } />
                </h5>
                <h5>gearType
                    <input className="field" type="text" value={formState.gearType}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                            setFormState({
                                ...formState,
                                gearType: e.target.value
                            })
                        } />
                </h5>
                <h5>gas
                    <input className="field" type="text" value={formState.gas}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                            setFormState({
                                ...formState,
                                gas: e.target.value
                            })
                        } />
                </h5>
                <h5>dailyPrice
                    <input className="field" type="text" value={formState.dailyPrice}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                            setFormState({
                                ...formState,
                                dailyPrice: e.target.value
                            })
                        } />
                </h5>
                <h5>monthlyPrice
                    <input className="field" type="text" value={formState.monthlyPrice}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                            setFormState({
                                ...formState,
                                monthlyPrice: e.target.value
                            })
                        } />
                </h5>
                <h5>thumbnailUrl
                    <input className="field " type="text" value={formState.thumbnailUrl}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                            setFormState({
                                ...formState,
                                thumbnailUrl: e.target.value
                            })
                        } />
                </h5>

            </Form>

            <Button onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
            }}>
                submit
            </Button>
        </div >
    );
}```
````

I am able to use the mutation or query via the GraphQL playground but am not able to update the database via adding data to the form. it just returns a blank page. What am I doing wrong here? Is there an easier way to input data?

I wanna add the data of the cars via the form but it returns a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

In the `onSubmit` callback you need to actually call the carForm function, passing the variables there. Just leave the `useMutation` with one param, and add the variables in the submit handler. Check out this pseudo-code:

```
const [carForm] = useMutation(ADD_NEW_CAR)

const submitHandler = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  await carForm({
   variables: {...} // useState variables.
  });
}

return <Form> 
  ...  
  <Button onSubmit={submitHandler}>Submit</Button>
</Form>
```